# MAX17048 - battery characterization data feeding

Tags: batteries, fuel-gauge

We are trying to use very common fuel guage - MAX17048. Multiple projects says that this chip will work as-is in your measurement of battery SOC/voltage and give accurate reading.

From what i know, every fuel guage needs to be fed with specific application battery characteristics to measure accurate SOC. Is it something wrong in my understanding ?

Also if MAX17048 does require specific battery characterisation data, has anyone stumbled upon 18650 1s battery characteristics which can be directly fed to MAX17048 ?

Comment: From the data sheet:  ModelGauge performs best with a custom model, obtained by characterizing the battery at multiple discharge currents and temperatures to precisely model it. At power-on reset (POR), the ICs have a preloaded ROM model that performs well for some batteries. Contact Maxim if you need a custom model.